# Invalid trial_end when trying to update an existing Subscription

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

When calling stripe's api to update a customer's subscription, I am getting an error. When users perform actions on my site, they can earn free months for their subscription. To give users free months, I'm trying to update the `trial_end` parameter to extend the free trial period. The error I'm getting is: `Invalid trial_end must be one of now`

```
new_end_dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)
new_end_ts = new_end_dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()

stripe.Subscription.modify(
    self.stripe_subscription_id,
    trial_end=new_end_ts,
    trial_from_plan=False,
)
```

Answer (score 15):

It turns out that the timestamp that i was passing stripe had a decimal in it. The timestamp was `1560360533.0` and this was causing problems. When I truncate the timestamp to remove the decimal everything worked properly. here's the line of code that fixed it:

`new_end_ts = round(new_end_dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())`